# Seeding initial user on Identity module without double-seeding

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, abp

I'm trying to use the ABP's identity module and have a seed for my first (admin) user.

In the identity module seed contributor's source code I see this:

```
public Task SeedAsync(DataSeedContext context)
{
    return _identityDataSeeder.SeedAsync(
        context["AdminEmail"] as string ?? "admin@abp.io",
        context["AdminPassword"] as string ?? "1q2w3E*",
        context.TenantId
    );
}
```

So in my migrator module I added this:

```
public override void OnApplicationInitialization(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
{
    using (var scope = context.ServiceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        var dataSeeder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataSeeder>();
        var dsCtx = new DataSeedContext
        {
            ["AdminEmail"] = "my@admin-email", 
            ["AdminPassword"] = "my-admin-password"
        };
        AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => dataSeeder.SeedAsync(dsCtx));
    }
    base.OnApplicationInitialization(context);
}
```

This works... however there's probably another module creating a data seeder (more likely the one that actually gets executed on the migrator, but I can't really find it), so all my contributors (and probably the module contributors) get executed twice (that's to be expected, I guess).

Is there any way I can change the seeding context without actually running an `IDataSeeder`? and if this can't be done... is there a way I can "unregister" all `IDataSeeder`s previous to mine so only mine gets executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this specific question (although I was hoping to find a more "general" solution), was to change the actual contributor. On your domain module (or wherever you see fit: your migrator or whatever), just do:

```
// Remove the contributor for the module
context.Services.RemoveAll(t => t.ImplementationType == typeof(IdentityDataSeedContributor));
// Add my custom constributor
context.Services.AddTransient<IDataSeedContributor, MyCustomConstributor>();
```

Where the implementation of the contributor is simply a copy of the default:

```
public class MyCustomConstributor : IDataSeedContributor
{
    private readonly IIdentityDataSeeder _identityDataSeeder;

    public IdentityDataSeedContributor(IIdentityDataSeeder identityDataSeeder)
    {
        _identityDataSeeder = identityDataSeeder;
    }

    public Task SeedAsync(DataSeedContext context)
    {
        return _identityDataSeeder.SeedAsync(
            context["AdminEmail"] as string ?? "my@admin-email",
            context["AdminPassword"] as string ?? "my-admin-password",
            context.TenantId
        );
    }
}
```

Notice that you still get the username `admin` here... if you want to change it, you can just replace also the `IIdentityDataSeeder` implementation (using the same method, or the easier `Services.Replace`, which you can use since there should only be one implementation of `IIdentityDataSeeder`) and copy your own from the default one, changing the searched username.

For now, replacing the services on your module seems the way to go. Maybe the possibility to directly intercept the initialization stages of other modules might be there on future versions, but I haven't seen how for now.